# Unable to extract Powerpoint textbox contents into Excel using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, textbox, powerpoint, vba

Okay so I've managed to write the following code so far but i keep getting a `424 object required` error on the line beginning with `range`. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

```
Sub GetText()     
    Set PPApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")  
    i = 1
    Do While i <= PPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Count
       If PPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(i).Type = msoTextBox Then
          range(Cells(i, 15)).Value = PApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(i).TextFrame.TextRange.Text
       End If
       i = i + 1
    Loop 
End Sub
```

Comment: replace `range(Cells(i, 15)).Value` with `Cells(i, 15).Value`

Comment: if it is PPT then why you are using range(Cells(i,15)), PPT consist of Shape, TextArea. Dim oRng As TextRange  \n   Set oRng = oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
            
\n               Set oTmpRng = oRng.Find( _
\n               FindWhat:=searchtext, _
\n                WholeWords:=False, _
\n                matchcase:=matchvalue)

Comment: @simoco thank you for the suggestion but i keep getting the same error

Comment: @Brain, thank you for your help... I am relatively new to vba so i am not quite sure how to apply your suggestion into my code. I would appreciate it if you could assist me with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two errors in your code.

1. Simoco has already addressed your first error. i.e you need to use `Cells(i, 15).Value` instead of `range(Cells(i, 15)).Value`
2. You have a typo. If you would have used `Option Explicit` then you would have known where the error is ;)

You have `PPApp` as the powerpoint object but are using `PApp` and hence the `object required error`

Also please declare your variables and fully qualify your objects.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetText()
    Dim PPApp As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set PPApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")

    i = 1

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Do While i <= PPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Count
       If PPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(i).Type = msoTextBox Then
          ws.Cells(i, 15).Value = PPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(i).TextFrame.TextRange.Text
       End If
       i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Few Other observations.

1. You are using `GetObject`. If there are multiple instances of powerpoint then you many not get the correct result.
2. You are incrementing the value of `i` even when the shape is not `msoTextBox`. This may result in you skipping the rows while writing to the Excel Sheet. You may want to use a different variable and increment that inside the `If-EndiF`

Comment: Thank you so much that is fantastic! I really appreciate the additional observations also and will make sure i adjust the macro accordingly